# ASP.NET MVC using same view to edit and create

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, edit

I've created a View for editing my Model. The View is strongly-typed and at one point I do the following:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Risks.Count; i++)
    {   
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Risks[i]))
    }
```

Now, this is working fine if the collection is not null, i.e if I edit an existing Entity.

However I'd like to use this same View for creating a new Entity. But it crashes since the collection is null. How can I make sure it renders the editor ?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have defaults for when the model is new.

```
public IList<Risk> Risks {
  get {
      return IsNew() ? DefaultRisks() : risks;
  }
  set {
    risks = value;
  }
}
```

Having a property IsNew can then be used in the view for example button text "Create" or "Save"

If you end up with too many if statements in your view it would be best to seperate them.

That being said having the same presentation model is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an EditorTemplate and get rid of any loops in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Risks)
```

Now ASP.NET MVC will detect at runtime if the collection is empty and do nothing or if it has values it will automatically render the corresponding editor template for each element of the collection. This way you are killing two birds with one stone: your code is much easier and you don't need to be doing any tests => you are leaving this task to the ASP.NET MVC framework.

Comment: Darin, are you implying that the loop should be placed in the EditorTemplate instead ? So that if the Risks colleciton is empty then it won't be rendered. Ok, but what if I'm trying to create a new Risk ? I need to have some empty controls rendered on screen.

Comment: @user1098555, I am implying that you shouldn't be using any loops. Get rid of it. ASP.NET MVC will automatically recognize that Risks is a collection and render the corresponding editor template for each element of this collection. It will do it for you so that you don't have to be writing any loops. All you have to do is put `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Risks)` as shown in my answer.

Comment: I need a loop, because I use inheritance in my ViewModel and the editor template should be different according to the type of Risk in the collection. Does it make sense ?